# Stretching responsive elements on percentage

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've created some mobile share buttons and I'd like each button to have a width of 33%, but they're not stretching across at the moment.

I'm not sure if `<li>` already has some styling that's breaking this, or if I'm missing something:

```
<div class="mobile-share-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><script>
            var strPostUrl = &quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;;
            document.write(&quot;<a class='mobile-share-button' id='fb-mobile-button' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot;+strPostUrl+&quot;' target='_blank'>Facebook</a>&quot;);
        </script></li>

        <li><script>
            var strPostUrl = &quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;;
            var strPostTitle = &#39;<data:post.title/>&#39;;
            document.write(&quot;<a class='mobile-share-button' id='twitter-mobile-button' href='https://twitter.com/share?text=&quot;+strPostTitle+&quot;&amp;url=&quot;+strPostUrl+&quot;&amp;via=MTS_Collective' target='_blank'>Twitter</a>&quot;);
        </script></li>

        <li style='padding-right:none;'><script>
            var strPostUrl = &quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;;
            var strPostTitle = &#39;<data:post.title/>&#39;;
            var strNewUrl = strPostUrl.replace(&quot;http://&quot;,&quot;&quot;);
            var strNewTitle = strPostTitle.replace(/&quot;/g, &#39;&quot;&#39;);
            document.write(&quot;<a class='mobile-share-button' id='tumblr-mobile-button' href='http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=&quot;+strNewUrl+&quot;&amp;name=&quot;+strNewTitle+&quot;' target='_blank'>Tumblr</a>&quot;);
        </script></li>
  </ul>
</div>

        .mobile-share-bar {
            display: inline;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .mobile-share-bar ul {
            -webkit-padding-start: 0;
            padding-bottom: 4px;
        }

        .mobile-share-bar li {
            display: inline;
            width: 33%;
            list-style-type: none;
            padding-right: 5px;
        }

        .mobile-share-button {
            margin: 0.5em 0;
            -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px;
            -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px;
            -ms-border-radius: 4px 4px;
            -o-border-radius: 4px 4px;
            border-radius: 4px 4px;
            background-color: #3b5999;
            border-color: #8f8f8f;
            box-shadow: none;
            padding: 6px;
            text-shadow: none;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 0.8125em;
            letter-spacing: 0.125em;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        #fb-mobile-button {
            background-color: #3b5999;
        }

        #twitter-mobile-button {
            background-color: #00b0ed;
        }

        #tumblr-mobile-button {
            background-color: #3f5a6f;
        }

        a#fb-mobile-button.mobile-share-button, a#twitter-mobile-button.mobile-share-button, a#tumblr-mobile-button.mobile-share-button
        {
            color: #fff;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Website: http://www.mtscollective.com (on responsive)

Comment: Try to replicate your problem in a fiddle instead. Linking to an external site makes the question susceptible to losing context due to link rot, making it less useful for future users.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't render anything. The problem is that it loses inherited styling and becomes inaccurate.

Comment: Emphasis on the word *replicate* — it's not all about copying and pasting your code. Also, by isolating the CSS for the elements in question, you might even be able to find the source of the trouble yourself. See this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: does my answer help you? if not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is setting the width on an inline element. see this fiddle:

```
.mobile-share-bar li {
  display: block;
  float:left;
  width: 32%;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 1%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/John_C/4dHkb/

Comment: I understand what you mean, but they're still not displaying correctly. The perimeter for each button stretches, but not the button itself.

Comment: OK, to do that you'll need to add styling to the buttons themselves. Something like: a.mobile-share-button{display:block; width:95%;}

Comment: Almost got it. I'm not sure how to prevent padding on the last button, or why the list items look like they're outside of the list when inspecting the elements.

Comment: Ok, that's 2 separate questions. To get the last item to line up I'd replace the padding-right with padding-left and then remove it from the first li item using the :first-child pseudo-selector. The ul has a height of zero since its child elements are floated. You can set the height of the ul if you want to change that.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks so much! The issue now is that the buttons/items don't appear to stretch all the way across (less on larger screens). I've set the `a.mobile-share-button` width to 90% - 100% stretches all the way on my laptop, but too far on my iPhone.

Comment: Cool, I took a look at the site again and you've got the hang of it now. To get it to line up, the main think is to ensure that all with widths and padding add up to 100%.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55633/discussion-between-john-c-and-mario-parra).

Comment: I've replied in the chat.

Answer (score 0):

try this changes, I have edit display and width property (remove padding right)

```
.mobile-share-bar li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 32%;
}
```